# Retrieve values from hashmap (.values())

Tags: java, collections

I would be pleasure if you can suggest.
Could you suggest how properlly I can retriev all values from hashmap. 
In such simplee example:

```
    Map<String, Values> someMap = ....;
    List<Values> valuesFromMap = (List<Values>) someMap.values();
```

After that I've got that, Java couldn't cast to java.util.List

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someMap.values()` returns `Collection`. If you need to convert into `List` than do that as follows:

```
 List<Values> valuesFromMap = new ArrayList<>(someMap.values());
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`values` method returns a `Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), not a `List`.  Use

```
Collection<Values> valuesFromMap = someMap.values();
```